# Como entro desde windows al linux de un módem ZTE MF823

Tags: javascript, html, linux, windows

tengo una duda , quisiera modificar la interfaz web de un módem ZTE , este modem tiene un sistema Linux adentro y puedo ingresar a la interfaz desde el navegador http://192.168.0.1.

Quisiera entrar al html ,css, js. ect.. pero no se como

He intentado con Ext2fsd y Explore2fs pero no me funciona

¿hay alguna forma de entrar y pueda modificar el codigo que tiene ese modem con linux desde windows?

Le agradezco sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente los dispositivos propietarios no apuestan por el código abierto para que pueda ser leído y mucho menos modificado. El código del sistema operativo así como el de la interfaz web estará inaccesible para el usuario y seguramente escrito en una memoria de solo lectura.

Comment: Pero es linux , debería ser libre a código abierto , creo ....

Answer (score 0):

Primero revisa en la configuracion GUI de tu modem que los puertos 22 o 23 esten abiertos o que ssh o telnet estén habilitados.

Luego ya que confirmaste el paso anterior, tu modem tiene la IP 192.168.0.1, desde cualquier consola que alcance esa IP podrias hacer telnet o ssh.

Por ultimmo haz: telnet 192.168.0.1

[Aquí](https://blog.elevendroids.com/2014/06/changing-zte-mf823-4g-modem-ip-address/) mencionan algo de eso